# css-container border should be take full screen

Tags: html, css

I am having a very simple requirement.I need the border on left and right should continue no matter what the browser screen is.i.e top and bottom portion should remain white but left and right should be black.In short the final result should be like below image
http://s13.postimage.org/uuy4fobxj/border.jpg

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    font-family: Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif,Arial;
    height: 100%!important;
    }
#container {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 0 none;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 978px !important;
    overflow:auto;
}   
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="container">
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a rather common thing in web dev, which is to center content on the page, am I right? this works for me...

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html,body
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif,Arial;
    height: 100%!important;
    }
#container {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    width: 978px !important;
    overflow:auto;
}   
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="container">
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: will it be same if I am having float element inside of container?

Comment: I use floats in the container I use in a similar design and it works fine. the floats should respect the container.

Comment: can you quickly check ojs.monojitbanerjee.co.cc and let me know?

Answer (score 0):

I think your !important statements were messing up with your rules, this worked for me:

```
body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#FAFAFA;
    text-align:center;
}

#container {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height:100%;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height:100%;
    width:978px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-left:1px solid #CCC;
    border-right:1px solid #CCC;
    overflow:auto;
}
```